# Exclude child pages args array

Tags: pages, exclude, child-pages

I have the following code and need it to exclude the child pages of a page ID;

```
<?php
      $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'page',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                    'exclude' => '3984,1939,6006,28,2784',
                    'depth' => 1
                );
                     $postslist = get_posts($args);
                     foreach ($postslist as $post) :
                        setup_postdata($post);
                     ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('portrait');} else { echo '<img src="#" alt="Something Went Wrong?" title="Sorry - Something went wrong?" />';}?>    
                    </a>
                        <span><?php meta('issue-number'); ?></span>
                </li>

     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The 'Depth' does not seem to have any effect...

Thanks!

Comment: I think the exclude needs to be an array. so something like: `'exclude' => array(3984,1939,6006,28,2784),` might work. Would need to check this though.

Comment: Thanks, but i am not sure you have understood - if you look at the code, i am already excluding individual pages, but i want all child pages of ID= x to be excluded automatically.

Comment: Oh sorry. I thought the exclude IDs were the child pages. Use the [get_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) function instead. It has the appropriate `exclude_tree` param that will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

There is not depth parameter for get_posts. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

You will need to check to see whether the page has a parent and display it if it does not have a parent.

Once you are in the foreach loop add an if statement

```
<?php if( !$post->parent ): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('portrait');} else { echo '<img src="#" alt="Something Went Wrong?" title="Sorry - Something went wrong?" />';}?></a>
     <span><?php meta('issue-number'); ?></span>
     </li>
<?php endif: ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                <?php
      $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'page',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                    'exclude' => '3984,1939,6006,28,2784',
                    'exclude_tree' => '1939',
                    'sort_order' => 'desc'
                );
                     $postslist = get_pages($args);
                     foreach ($postslist as $post) :
                        setup_postdata($post);

                     ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('portrait');} else { echo '<img src="#" alt="Something Went Wrong?" title="Sorry - Something went wrong?" />';}?>    
                    </a>
                        <span><?php meta('issue-number'); ?></span>
                </li>

     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks to Phoenix - all i needed to do was have get_pages instead. This opened up the extra options i needed